# Python - replace prints by a function

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, numpy

What I have:

```
import numpy as np
l = np.array([['a11','a12'],['a21','a22']])
layout = '{!s:6}'*2
for i in range(np.shape(l)[1]):
    print(layout.format(*l[i]))
```

Output:

```
a11   a12   
a21   a22
```

What I want:

```
def table (two_dim_array):
    (i,j) = np.shape (two_dim_array)
    layout = '{!s:6}'*j
    #for k in range (i):
        #return layout.format(*two_dim_array[k])
    return 'a string that matches the table printed above'
```

I guess the above code is self explanatory. I'd like to rewrite the above output in the form of a function which would output a string matching the above print.

Comment: Hi андрэ, I don't quite understand. What does this code currently do and what would you like it to do? Also, the two lines after "#output" make me think this won't compile if I try to run it; should those be non-code blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `print(x)` writes `x` and `\n` to stdout. So, you basically want to replace each `print(x)` with `return_value += x + '\n'`.

Therefore:

```
return_value = ''
for i in range(np.shape(l)[1]):
    return_value += layout.format(*l[i]) + '\n'
return return_value
```

Another way would be using `str.join` and a generator expression:

```
return '\n'.join(layout.format(*l[i]) for i in range(np.shape(l)[1]))
```

But then again, you don't need the `layout = '{!s:6}'*j` part either:

```
return '\n'.join(''.join('{!s:6}'.format(cell) for cell in row)
                 for row in two_dim_array)
```

Comment: Very clear. This generator expression is very interesting. Reminds me of list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

More or less replace `print` with `return`:

```
def table (two_dim_array):
    layout = '{!s:6}' * two_dim_array.shape[1]    
    return '\n'.join(layout.format(*row) for row in two_dim_array)
```